# If the addresses are different, how is the list updated together?

Tags: kotlin

There are some parts that I do not understand well while studying the list.

I created a new list using `Collections.unmodifiableList(list)`.

And I added an item to the `previous list`, and the item was also added to the newly created list.

I obviously thought the new list was returned, pointing to a different `address`, and I thought it was separate, but the result was completely different.

As in the image, the address of the debugging result is different as `@829` (old list) and `@830` (newly created list).

What happened?

---

```
fun main() {
    val list = arrayListOf(Student(), Student(), Student())
    val test = Collections.unmodifiableList(list)

    list.add(Student()) // Student is added along with test
}

class Student() { }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs of that method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) says that it creates a “view” of the other List. That means it is a wrapper around the other List used to prevent consumers of it from using the mutating methods. Since it is a wrapper, it has a distinct memory address. Since it is a view, it will always show the latest changes to the original List that it is referencing.

To get what you want, you need to copy the List which you can do in Kotlin by using `toList()`.

Comment: thanks. As you said, `unmodifiableList` seems to be the purpose of preventing users from tampering with the List as its name suggests.

But like the code I wrote in the OP, when I added it to the previous list, it was added as well, but is this not prevented at all?

Comment: @ybybyb `unmodifiableList` doesn't return an immutable list, it returns a read-only list. The only thing it prevents is consumers casting the list to a mutable one and making changes, it doesn't prevent changes through the original list

Comment: And it’s designed for Java, where you normally wouldn’t have to cast a List to start modifying it.

Answer (score 3):

`Collections.unmodifiableList` returns a wrapper that doesn't allow modifications. It doesn't make a defensive copy, that that's why you see this behaviour.

From the javadocs (the key is the word *view*):

> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list [...]

Comment: thanks. By the way, if you add it to the previous list like the `OP`'s code, it's changed, so isn't it allowed to be modified?

Comment: The original list (`list`) can be modified, and `test` is just a wrapper (or view) on the original list. If you take a look at the code of `Collections.unmodifiableList` you'll see that it returns an instance of `UnmodifiableList`. This implementation thorws an exception on all methods that would modify it (add, addAll, etc). Usually, the correct way of using `Collections.unmodifiable*` is to throw away whatever collection was used to create it in order to prevent changing the backing collection by mistake.